# Nginx not redirecting to path properly

Tags: nginx

I have this nginx config

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {


    server {
        listen              443 ssl;
        server_name         192.168.52.89;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate     /path/config/certfile.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /path/config/keyfile.key;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        location /auth-foo {
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.52.89:2085;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.51.90:3000;
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at this file several times and cross checked with resources online and somehow this still doesn't work well. I expect that when a request is made as: `192.168.52.89/auth-foo` nginx should push the request to `http://192.168.52.89:2085` but what I get is not found. Is there something I'm missing?

Am I missing something important?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you expecting a request to `http://192.168.52.89/auth-foo` to be redirected to `http://192.168.52.89:2085/auth-foo` or to `http://192.168.52.89:2085`?

Comment: I expect `http://192.168.52.89/auth-foo` to be redirected to `http://192.168.52.89:2085` @WillKeeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    server_name         192.168.52.89;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /path/config/certfile.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/config/keyfile.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    location = /auth-foo {
        return 302 /auth-foo/;  # Note the trailing slash
    }

    location /auth-foo/ {  # Note the trailing slash
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.52.89:2085/;  # Note the trailing slash
    }
```

Note the extra `location`, and also note the trailing slashes in 3 places (comments added to highlight).